# DAX Measure: IF sum of all users = Max THEN return value of individual user

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerpivot, powerquery

He Everyone,

I newer to DAX measures and I am trying to get my measure to have the following logic:

```
When sum of all users = Max, THEN return value of individual user
```

The Data Model has the following columns: CustomerID \ Usage \ Interval (DATETIME). What is tripping me up is that DATETIME is in 15-minute increments. I have approximately 700 unique CustomerIDs and I need to be able to return the usage of each CustomerID during the MAXSUM of all the CustomerIDs.

I am not sure if this would be an IF-THEN statement or if I need to use a time function.  I am writing this DAX measure in Power Pivot to send to a Pivot Table within Excel.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do your table(s) look like and how is Max calculated?

Comment: The Data Model has the following columns:

Comment: The Data Model has the following columns: CustomerID \ Usage \ Interval (DATETIME).  What is tripping me up is that DATETIME is in 15-minute increments.  I have approximately 700 unique CustomerIDs and I need to be able to find what DATETIME that the MAX occurs of the SUM of all 700 CustomerID USAGE and then I need to figure out what was the individual USAGE for each CustomerID at that DATETIME.

Comment: OK. You should probably edit that information into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the simplest solution, but it works for me (I've named the table `Load`).

```
CustomerUsage = 
    VAR Summarized = CALCULATETABLE(
                         SUMMARIZE(Load, Load[Interval], "TotalUsage", SUM(Load[Usage])),
                         ALLSELECTED(Load))
    VAR MaxUsage = MAXX(Summarized, [TotalUsage])
    VAR MaxInterval = MAXX(FILTER(Summarized, [TotalUsage] = MaxUsage), [Interval])
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Load[Usage]), Load[Interval] = MaxInterval)
```

First, you generate a table that finds the total usage per interval by summing over all selected users.

The `MaxUsage` is simply the largest `TotalUsage` over all of the intervals.

The `MaxInterval` is the interval for which the `TotalUsage = MaxUsage`.

Then we can find the `Usage` for a customer for the interval with maximum usage.

Comment: Amazing thank you!  Worked great.  I am still reading through the code to understand fully how it works.  I am starting to get it the more and more I read through it.